# row from odbc array isn't showing index and variable properly, illegal string offset

Tags: php, arrays

Not sure what I've done here, but I've been trying to run this select, get the row values and use a foreach in order to call a function with those values (coming in as arguments for the function) for an insert down the line.

I was getting illegal string offset errors and undefined variable so I dumped it into the array shown below.

How can I properly alter this to get "PR" = "ABCD" and so on?

```
public  function ref()
{

    $sql = "select cast(co as DECIMAL) as co, cast(sl as DECIMAL)as sl, cast(pr as character(10)) as pr, cast(qt as decimal) as qt FROM tailbone";
    $results = odbc_exec($this->DB2Conn, $sql);

    $log='';
    if ($results) {
        while($row = odbc_fetch_array($results))
        {
                var_dump($row);

                $res = $this->add_quota($results['sl'], $results['pr'], $results['qt'], $results['co']);


        }
    }
}
```

array dump:

```
array(4)
 ["CO"]=>
 string(1) "1"
 ["SL"]=>
 string(1) "1"
 ["PR"]=>
 string(4) "ABCD"
 ["QT"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Comment: You `var_dump` the `$row` but using the `$results`

Comment: So I should use the row? But should it still be $row['SL'] etc.?

Comment: Yes. Well I'm not sure what you using them for in the `add_quota` but using the `$result` object is definitely not the way (else what the for loop for?). I also guessing 'CO' is short for 'COMPN' and so on? This is very similar to you previous question - why is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `var_dump($results)` you will get something similar to this

```
resource(5) of type (odbc result)
```

This means `odbc_exec` returns a resource and you can't use that as an array. But since you're getting

> illegal string offset

Then this means you're trying to access a string like an associative array. However, since as we know now `$results` is a resource type then there's a high chance that the error message you're seeing happens in the `add_quota` method.

So in that method you may find something like this

```
function add_quota(...$args) {
    $args[0]['string']; // this is wrong, strings have no string keys
}
```

So what you should do is

```
public  function ref()
{

    $sql = "select cast(co as DECIMAL) as co, cast(sl as DECIMAL)as sl, cast(pr as character(10)) as pr, cast(qt as decimal) as qt FROM tailbone";
    $results = odbc_exec($this->DB2Conn, $sql);

    $log='';
    if ($results) {
        while($row = odbc_fetch_array($results))
        {
            $res = $this->add_quota($row['sl'], $row['pr'], $row['qt'], $row['co']);
        }
    }
}
```

`$row` here is an array containing the results returned by `odbc_fetch_array` function.